# Error al visualizar un reporte crystal report vs2010 en la version vs2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Cree un proyecto en c# con reportes en crystal report en esa ocasión con Visual Studio 2010, al tratar de abrir y ejecutar el proyecto en Visual Studio 2012 no me corren los reportes!!!

Habra que hacer algún cambio al código o a las referencias??

Por favor ayuda, estoy en apuros

Comment: Hola, ¿te sale algun error?

Comment: El error que me aparece es el siguiente:  ***'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer' no contiene una definición de 'cachedPageNumberPerDoc'.... *** El error esta en el Designer.cs

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que tanto VS2010 como VS2012 no tiene integrado Crystal report con el diseñador del VS, sino que debes instalarlo por separado

Puedes descargarlo de aqui

[SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio: Updates & Runtime Downloads](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

si abres un .rpt en el diseñador del VS entonces tienes Crystal integrado y con los componente necesario para ejecutar desde el entorno de desarrollo

Para el deploy es otro tema porque necesitaras los redistribuibles, los cuales deberas instalar en la pc del usuario

[Download Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Download-Crystal-Reports-for-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx)

Comment: Si lo acabo de instalar, y se instalo sin ningun problema sin en cambio nw sigue dando error

Comment: pero puedes desde el VS abrir un rpt y ver su diseño ? cual es el error que recibes?

Comment: no nisiquiera abre el rpt, y al tratar de compilar el error que me aparece es el siguiente: ***'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer' no contiene una definición de 'cachedPageNumberPerDoc'.... *** El error esta en el Designer.cs

Comment: pero sino abre el rpt entonces no se integro crystal con el VS Edite la respuesta, valida en el link que he puesto a ver si eso permite la integracion

Comment: que version de .net estas usando en el proyecto? es .net 4.5, porque quizas esto afecte

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta, descargare e instalare y te mantendre al tanto de los resultados

Comment: Es la version 4.5

Comment: El reporte fue creado en VS2010, ahora estoy usando el VS2012 puede ser esto el causante del problema?

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en la version que descargue de Crystal report, descargue otra y funciono 100% gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar qué versión daba el error, qué error específico y con qué versión se solucionó? Incluso si hay información en la web de este error, mucho mejor

Comment: Si añades los detalles que comenta mariano seguro muchas personas valoraran positivamente tu aportación